# Sessions in Sinatra: Used to Pass Variable

Tags: ruby, session, sinatra

So I have a piece of code that looks like:

```
post '/calendar' do
  #pull variables from form
  @cal = a.makeCal(form, variables) #do some work here with variables
  session["value"] == @cal
  haml :calendar
end
```

And then I have this:

```
get '/print' do
   @cal = session["value"]
   haml :print
end
```

What I did to test this was created a calendar by posting the form to /calendar. Next I went to /print manually, I expected my variable @cal to persist inside the cookie. Should I have? Am I doing this right?

What I'm trying to do is take the @cal value which is four arrays inside each other and pass it onto the print page without having to recalculate @cal. Is trying to do this via sessions the right way to do it?

Comment: The only 'not right way' about this is that, depending on the size of your array, using cookie-backed sessions may be passing a lot of information in the cookies for both response-and-request from then on. How big is `require "base64"; Base64.encode64(Marshal.dump(@cal)).length`?

Comment: @Phrogz When I run that it gives me '6666' is that too big?

Comment: Yes; anything over 4k is not guaranteed to work, and won't work in many browsers. You should consider using a better session store, such as memory-backed, file-backed, or db-backed sessions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in your `post` route:

```
session["value"] == @cal
#                ^^ compares for equality, does not set.
```

This will not affect the session, but will just evaluate to either `true` or (more likely) `false`.

What sort of object is `@cal`, and what are you using for your session backing? (Are these cookie-backed sessions, aka `Rack::Session::Cookie`, enabled via `enable :sessions`? If so, is your object definitely able to be serialized through Marshal?)

**Edit**

Yes, if you fix that typo, what you have should work.

Here's a test application that works for me...

```
require 'sinatra'
enable :sessions
get('/'){ haml :show_and_go }
post '/' do
  session["foo"] = [[[1,2],[3,4]],[5,6]]
  "Now get it!\n"
end
__END__
@@show_and_go
%p= session["foo"].inspect
%form(method='post' action='/')
  %button go
```

...and here is the testing of it in action. We see that with no cookies you get no session, but once the cookie has been written the very next request has it working. This works just as well in the browser, too:

```
phrogz$ cat cookies.txt
cat: cookies.txt: No such file or directory

phrogz$ curl http://localhost:4567/                      # GET
<p>nil</p>
<form action='/' method='post'>
  <button>go</button>
</form>

phrogz$ curl -d "" -c cookies.txt http://localhost:4567  # POST
Now get it!

phrogz$ curl -b cookies.txt http://localhost:4567        # GET, with cookies
<p>[[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [5, 6]]</p>
<form action='/' method='post'>
  <button>go</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm using enable :sessions, yes. I don't know for sure that it can be serialized. It is an array that is three arrays deep. For example @cal[0][0][0][0] is used to access elements.

Comment: That's readily serializable. I have no problem with this functionality; see the edit above.

Comment: I have your test code up and running, and I made the change from == to = in my code and I get: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass In my haml template the issue is being casued by this line: - @cal.each do |holder|

Comment: It looks like I'm going to have to figure out a new way to do this, but I did learn a bit from this experience! Thanks for teaching me.

Comment: @NoahClark Doing `session[:foo] = @bar` won't make `@bar` available in a later route unless you do `@bar = session[:foo]`.